# Execute ./script.sh with a crontab

Tags: debian, permissions, postgresql, dropbox

With `Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`, I'm using a simple script to save a `PostgreSQL` database and upload it to my `Dropbox` account with [Dropbox-Uploader](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader) tool. I schedule this task with a `crontab`.

When I directly execute my script from the prompt everything is ok and well executed, but when it run from the crontab the upload action isn't execute (`./dropbox_uploader.sh -d upload`).

Am I missing something in execute permissions ?

**The script** (my_script.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Database dump
pg_dump -U postgres -d my_database > /home/my_user/`date +%Y%m%d`_my_database.sql

# Upload to Dropbox
./dropbox_uploader.sh -d upload /home/my_user/`date +%Y%m%d`_my_database.sql `date +%Y%m%d`_my_database.sql
```

**Permissions**

```
 ls -l my_script.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my_user my_user 732 Apr  7 09:19 my_script.sh

getfacl  my_script.sh
# file:  my_script.sh
# owner: my_user
# group: my_user
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

ls -l dropbox_uploader.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 52481 Apr  6 16:01 dropbox_uploader.sh

getfacl dropbox_uploader.sh
# file: dropbox_uploader.sh
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

**Cron**

```
0 9 * * * /bin/sh /home/my_user/my_script.sh
```

I have read this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203371/run-script-sh-vs-bash-script-sh-permission-denied) and this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136547/what-is-the-difference-between-running-bash-script-sh-and-script-sh?rq=1), but I think I'm missing something with `dropbox_uploader.sh` execution permissions.

Comment: Replace relative paths (`./filename`) with absolute paths (`/path/to/filename`)

Comment: If you've written a bash script (as suggested by your `#!/bin/bash`) don't call it with `sh`; either use `bash` or better still make it executable and just treat it as any other program

Comment: When I call it in the crontab ? What difference it makes ? I ask it for my own knowledge and to acquire good practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your script and write the full path of the script dropbox_uploader.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Database dump
pg_dump -U postgres -d my_database > /home/my_user/`date +%Y%m%d`_my_database.sql

# Upload to Dropbox
/home/my_user/dropbox_uploader.sh -d upload /home/my_user/`date +%Y%m%d`_my_database.sql `date +%Y%m%d`_my_database.sql
```

Comment: So obvious, how can I miss this ? Thanks.