# read: illegal option -u

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, read

I am trying to use read, to read from a file descriptor, like so:

```
read -u fd
```

as in [in this link](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html).

Here is the code I am using in a bash script:

```
MESSAGE=$(read -u $NODE_CHANNEL_FD)
echo " parent message => $MESSAGE"  >&2
```

The exact error message:

```
read: Illegal option -u
```

Anyone know what this could possibly be about?

Comment: the file descriptor is definitely defined by NODE_CHANNEL_FD, so that shouldn't be part of the problem

Comment: if I run the bash script with the bash executable, instead of the sh executable, the error goes away. But what confuses me, is that at the top of the of the shell script, is the hashbang - #!/usr/bin/env bash, which I thought meant to tell sh to run the file with bash....

Comment: Among modern Bourne-like shells, only `bash`. `ksh` and `zsh` support `read -u <fd_num>`.

Comment: thanks, yeah, so any idea why /usr/bin/env might not be defined on my system? that's why this is not working AFAICT. The shebang won't work, because /usr/bin/env is not even a directory...I am on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Not sure why `/usr/bin/env` is relevant here. Ubuntu `/bin/sh` is linked to `/bin/dash`, so you may want to use `/bin/bash` instead.

Comment: it's relevant because I thought /usr/bin/env was universal, and that's what was at the top of my file as a shebang, I bet if I try #! /bin/bash it will work..thanks

Comment: LOL, my bad, I thought that /usr/bin/env was a directory, but of course env is program/executable, now I really don't why it doesn't work, but some progress is being made

Comment: If you are *explicitly* running the script with `sh` (e.g. `sh myscript`) then that will override the shebang line. Just make the file executable and run it by its path + name `./myscript`. See [What is the difference between running “bash script.sh” and “./script.sh”?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136547/what-is-the-difference-between-running-bash-script-sh-and-script-sh)

Comment: yeah I am explicitly running it with sh...I thought sh was responsible for finding the right interpreter, but I guess not, a lower level facility must do that...

Comment: I guess my question is - if I fork a process to run a shell script...how can I know whether to fork an sh or bash process? Do I manually have to read the shebang of the file or go by the extension name of the file?

Comment: `./script` should do it

Comment: Right but I am running this script as a child process from Node.js...I simply don't know how to start a child process in Node.js to run a script that doesnt invoke either sh or bash directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message suggests that you are in fact not executing the script using `bash`.

Either make the script executable and add a proper `#!`-line on the first line of the script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Or, execute the script with `bash` explicitly:

```
$ bash script.sh
```

You should treat `sh` and `bash` as implementing separate languages, and use the correct interpreter for the script you're writing. In this case, you're using `read` with the `-u` option. This is originally a `ksh` extension to the standard `read` specification, and it's also implemented in `bash` and `zsh`. Hence, you need to run the script with `bash`, `zsh` or `ksh`.

How to know when to use `sh` and when to use `bash` or some other shell? It's simple, you learn the way `sh` works and what other features other shells add.

Comment: `-u` was initially a `ksh` extension. Also supported by `zsh` and `bash`. One can always use `read <&"$fd"` in standard `sh` to get the same effect.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You're better at shell history than what I am...

Comment: There are very few features that are native to `bash`. Most for come from ksh and csh, a few from zsh and mksh. If in doubt, you can always check the [ksh86](https://github.com/weiss/original-bsd/blob/master/local/toolchest/ksh/sh.m) or [ksh88](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ksh&manpath=SunOS%205.5.1) (here ksh88i, but there has been little [evolution](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shells/ksh88-fixes) in ksh88 feature-wise since 1988) man pages. If it's not in ksh88, it may come from ksh93, but then, you'd need to check if it was added in bash or ksh93 first.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks! I appreciate the pointers.