# Why is "bash -x" required to make my script.sh bash file run?

Tags: shell-script, linux-mint

I have a simple bash file script that sets proper resolution for my VM (1920x1080) in Linux Mint v18.1:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync 
xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080`
```

Worth noting, I originally had this script living on my desktop, but I have since copied it to /etc/init.d/ but it still does not run without appending `bash -x` before `./script.sh` Can anyone tell me why this is and what I can do to fix it?

EDIT:  I was just attempting to run the script incorrectly (I blame PowerShell):
`noob_me@linux-mint$ .\reso.sh
.reso.sh: command not found`

Once I ran it like so `./script.sh` it works fine.

Comment: update question to show what happens if you try `./script.sh` alone ?

Comment: Use a forward slash instead of a backslash.  And I don't know why it *would* work with `bash -x .\script.sh`; it shouldn't.  The backslash will be removed, so `.script.sh` should be the result.

Comment: I suppose thats a typo...

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136547/135943

Comment: Sorry, I was confused because I am a Windows SysAdmin and most of the time I am running things in PowerShell where you use .\ to run scripts and .EXE's. I'll edit the post to make it correct and use a forward-slash.

Comment: I wonder if you wrote the script in an editor that put carriage returns and newlines in instead of just newlines?

Comment: I think I used the default text program in Linux Mint, yes. I should have just used Nano in the terminal.

Comment: @SamAndrew81, If the problem was just a typo, why did you accept an answer?

Comment: I don't know, it's seemed applicable. I will undo that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add execute permissions to the file, if you haven't already, in order to run it on its own. You can do that with `chmod`. `chmod u+x filename` will add execute permissions for the file owner, `chmod a+x filename` will add them for everyone.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, I ran `chmod +x` (that is not the same, I take it?)

Comment: @SamAndrew81 `chmod +x` seems to have the same affect as `chmod a+x`. If it's still not working, what is the error message that you get when you try to run it? Without the error message, we're all just guessing in the dark.

Answer (score 2):

If the script runs with `bash -x`, then it also runs without it, as the only thing which `bash -x <file>` does, is running the script in debug mode by tracing each executed command.

Comment: `bash -x` is not only enabling the debug mode - it is also calling the bash interpreter explicitly and this makes the script to run. If the script has not execute permissions you can run it either with `bash -x file.sh` or with a plain `bash file.sh` , but not with `./file.sh`