# Pause execution of a list of commands

Tags: bash, pipe, read

I have a file that has a list of bash commands like the following:

```
echo 'foobar'
echo 'helloworld'
echo 'ok'
```

And I can execute these commands by simply piping them to `/bin/bash` like so:

```
cat commands | /bin/bash
```

Now, how do I pause the execution right in the middle, and wait for the user input? Using `read` does not seem to work.

```
echo 'foobar'
echo 'helloworld'
read -p 'Press ENTER to continue'
echo 'ok'
```

Comment: Curiosity killed the cat...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute like this:

```
/bin/bash commands
```

---

Piping the file to `bash` makes the file travel via stdin of `bash`. In such case `read`, reading from stdin, reads from the piped stream instead of from the terminal. It consumes `echo 'ok'`. By specifying the file as an argument to `bash` you still execute it, this time the stdin is not redirected though.

I assume you want to execute like this. Compare [What is the difference between running `bash script.sh` and `./script.sh`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136547/108618)